# Deleting views from xml (android)

Tags: android, xml

here's my problem:
I had two buttons in one of my activities, then i decided to put their functional into OptionsMenu - so i did that and delete these buttons from my .xml layout file. I delete any references to these buttons but they're still visible. I think there's some bug but how can i get rid of this?

actually i have a similar problem with buttons in another activity, but it disappear after 2 or 3 compilations

Comment: You really need to provide more details like your layout XML and/or code for anybody to be able to help you.

Comment: Try Cleaning ur Project . I have also faced this issue . Even u can try uninstalling APP on Emulator/Handset and then installing new APP

Comment: Without knowing what environment you're using, it's hard to tell, but I'm guessing you're using Eclipse? If so, try just doing Project->Clean and clean the offending project, then try running it again. Sometimes Eclipse seems to get a bit confused about whether it needs to recompile Android project resources.

Comment: Yes, thank you, i cleaned my project and now it works:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a compilation issue. Clean your project and build again. 
If this still presists try restarting Eclipse.